# How to fix this error Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm making a simple CRUD, but my crud app shown an error message Message: Trying to get property of non-object in update form. This is my controller

```
public function ubah($id){
        $this->load->model('m_property');
        $data = array();
        $data['msg']            = $this->_get_flashdata();
        $data['category']       = $this->m_category->get(); 
        $data['notif']          = $this->m_property->count_properti();
        $data['notifikasi']     = $this->m_property->notif_properti();
        $data['data']           = $this->m_property->get_id($id);

        var_dump($data['data']);

        $html = array();
        $html['header']     = $this->load->view('admin/header',$data,true);
        $html['kiri']       = $this->load->view('admin/kiri',null,true);
        $html['content']    = $this->load->view('admin/belanja/ubah',$data,true);
        $this->load->view('admin/template',$html);
    }
```

This is my model

```
<?php 
    class M_property extends CI_Model {
        public function get_id($id){
            $this->db->where('nID', $id);
            $query = $this->db->get('properti');
            return $query->result();
        }

        public function update($id, $data){
            $this->db->where('nID', $id);
            return $this->db->update('properti', $data); 
        }
?>
```

And this my view

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6">
                            <h4 class="header green clearfix">
                                Nama Properti
                            </h4>
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="nama" value="<?php echo $data->nama ?>" />
                        </div>
```

An message error shown at this code

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="nama" value="<?php echo $data->nama ?>" />
```

I don't know what's problem on my code, can help me please?

Comment: Your question bit hard to under stand what your trying to achieve.

Comment: I'm trying to make CRUD apps but when I'm click a data for update and links  to upadate url in my form update shown an error **Message: Trying to get property of non-object**. I want to get data from my field. So what's my problem in my code ? Please help me

Comment: i get it.. question though, is the view you provided coming from this:`admin/header.php` or where is it located?

Comment: You should include the full error message.The error message tells where you got the error(line no and on what). Search at google why such type error we get.

Comment: @CodeGodie admin/content.php guys

Comment: @ShaifulIslam this is full error message 
**A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Trying to get property of non-object
Filename: belanja/ubah.php
Line Number: 27** 

I was checked at line number 27, at line number 27 this is my code 
**<input class="form-control" type="text" name="nama" value="<?php echo $data->nama ?>" />**
I feel it's true but still shown an error

Comment: The error message says $data does not exists means either its empty or your query did not return any record.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that your model you are using `$query->result();` which results in an array of objects. But in your view you are not taking that into account. Instead you are assuming its just one object outside of an array. If you want that, and if you know that you would only get a one row result, then change this:

```
$query->result();

/*
which would result insomething like this:
array[
   0 => {
          "key" : "value"
        } 
]
*/
```

to this:

```
$query->row();

/*
which would result insomething like this:
{
   "key" : "value"
}
*/
```

SOURCE: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html#result-rows

Comment: I was changed **$query->result();** to **$query->row()** bit its still show an error

Comment: thats weird.. there must be something else youre not showing us in your code, because this should work. What if you `var_dump($data)` before running your view? what do you get?

Comment: I've given **var_dump($data)** and the results is array empty

Answer (score 0):

The only object I can see at the line from the view that you mentioned is the $data object. The error message "...property of non-object..." might indicate that the $data object does not exist or that it is null.